# Summing up two rows of specific values in Grafana

Tags: mysql, grafana

Hello there people of stack overflow I once again ask for your knowledgeable support since I'm unable to do this simple task. So I want to add  [these two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwZq5.png) values together. Here's the query so far that displays People counting data by 30min increments from each individual camera:

```
SELECT
  my_time-INTERVAL 3 HOUR AS time,
  ip AS metric,
  enter_people
FROM camera_metric
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(my_time)
ORDER BY my_time
```

Since two of these cameras are counting the same spot I want their data to add up.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The problem was that I had to not use ip as metric, sum enter_people and do two queries where one exludes the two values ant this one includes them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had to not use ip as metric, sum enter_people and do two queries where one exludes the two values ant this one includes them.